# PHP SQL Update error

Tags: php, sql, database

I am having a wierd problem when attempting to update a table in my mysql server.

The code:

```
    $name = trim(FilterText($_POST['name']));
$description = trim(FilterText($_POST['description']));
$type = $_POST['type'];

if($groupdata['type'] == "3" && $_POST['type'] != "3"){ echo "You may not change the group type if it is set to 3."; exit; } // you can't change the group type once you set it to 4, fool
if($type < 0 || $type > 3){ echo "Invalid group type."; exit; } // this naughty user doesn't even deserve an settings update

if(strlen(HoloText($name)) > 25){
    echo "Name too long\n\n<p>\n<a href=\"".WWW."/groups/".$groupid."/id\" class=\"new-button\"><b>Done</b><i></i></a>\n</p>\n\n<div class=\"clear\"></div>";
} elseif(strlen(HoloText($description)) > 200){
    echo "Description too long\n\n<p>\n<a href=\"".WWW."/groups/".$groupid."/id\" class=\"new-button\"><b>Done</b><i></i></a>\n</p>\n\n<div class=\"clear\"></div>";
} elseif(strlen(HoloText($name)) < 1){
    echo "Please give a name\n\n<p>\n<a href=\"".WWW."/groups/".$groupid."/id\" class=\"new-button\"><b>Done</b><i></i></a>\n</p>\n\n<div class=\"clear\"></div>";  
} else {
    mysql_query("UPDATE groups SET name = '".$name."', type = $type, desc='".$description."' WHERE id = $groupid AND ownerid = '".USER_ID."' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Editing group settings successful\n\n<p>\n<a href=\"".WWW."/groups/".$groupid."/id\" class=\"new-button\"><b>Done</b><i></i></a>\n</p>\n\n<div class=\"clear\"></div>";
}
```

At the mysql_query to update groups, I keep getting an error saying that I have an error in my SQL syntax at the part when inserting desc=blahblahbla.

When I take the "desc" part out of the query, and only insert the name and type, the query works perfectly, but when I add the desc back into the query, it throws the error again. There are no '' in the desc part - which could stuff it up, and even if there were, I have filtered them at the start of the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using a CMS in case you were wondering

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

`desc` is a reserved word in MySQL, for use in `order by` clauses. You'll have to escape it with backticks:

```
UPDATE .... `desc`=etc...
            ^--  ^--
```

And of course, you'll also get jumped on by a few dozen busybodies who'll claim that using the mysql_*() functions will cause the universe to implode in 5... 4... 3...

Comment: Thanks for that! I didn't click with the "order by 'desc'" bit. Thanks a million!

Comment: Those busybodies are performing a public service.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `groups` SET `name` = '".$name."', `type` = $type, `desc` = '".$description."' WHERE `id` = '$groupid' AND `ownerid` = '".USER_ID."' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: If you're going to change a long string by only 2 characters, you should generally point out WHERE the changes are. We're human, we don't do 'diff' easily.